# React Native setState from BackHandler not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update the state of my App class through a BackHandler function (on back button pressed). Am I doing something wrong?
Here is my App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this._changeDisplayOpt = this._changeDisplayOpt.bind(this)
  }

  state = {
    screen: "room",
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  handleBackButton() {
    if(this.state.screen == "room"){
      this.setState({screen:'home'});
    }
    return true;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text>{this.state.screen}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

It gives me this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.screen')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your function as below

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleBackButton = this.handleBackButton.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        screen: "room",
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }

    handleBackButton() {
        if (this.state.screen == "room") {
            this.setState({ screen: 'home' });
        }
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.state.screen}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: If answer solved your problem. Please mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
```